# Convert Scss to Sass mixin

Tags: sass, mixins, code-conversion

I'm looking for some documentation on Mixins specifically for .Sass

Not .Scss

but due to the naming conventions they keep coming up with the same search results.

```
@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return $remSize * 1rem;
}

@mixin font-size($size) {
  font-size: $size;
  font-size: calculateRem($size);
}
```

`@mixin` becomes `=`

but further then this I don't know what `function` become etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sass-convert to convert your file from scss to sass

your code in sass is

```
@function calculateRem($size)
  $remSize: $size / 16px

  @return $remSize * 1rem

=font-size($size)
  font-size: $size
  font-size: calculateRem($size)
```

Reference
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly! 

I wasn't sure if `code`@function`code` and `code`@return`code` worked with Sass.

Comment: no problem. you can cross check your syntax in sass-convert. that tool is really useful.

Comment: if it helped you solve the problem. Please mark this as answer